# Array.binarySearch returning negative numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the index of a string in a string array using the Arrays.binarySearch() method however the method seems to be return the postion integer "-5" when looking for the string "Free". Any idea why this would be?

```
String[] names = {"Arken","Ben","Darklark", "Free","group"};

void changeFriends(String uname, boolean b)
        {   // change a friend's "online" status

    Arrays.sort(names);
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(names, uname);

    System.out.println("NAME OF ONLINE USER IS AT INDEX:" + index + "Name:" + uname);
        if(index > -1)
        {

             if(b == true)
            {
                loggedOn[index] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                loggedOn[index] = false;
            }
        }
        // call method to update buttons
        changeNameButtons();
    }
```

Comment: I tested your code, it returns `NAME OF ONLINE USER IS AT INDEX: 3 Name:Free`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, i just ran your code and i got the index 3.

```
Arrays.sort(names);
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(names, "Free");
System.out.println(index);
```

you  probably are searching `free` or `Free`(with a trailing white space) instead of `Free`, in which case it returns -5.

Comment: @MadProgrammer haha, i was not being rude, anyhow chhanged it :)

Comment: I didn't think you where, but not everyone will see it that way ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see no 'harsh' comment in any of the edits. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP - It was simply my opinion, it just felt a "little" off hand.  Remember, the meaning of communication is the meaning that the receiver makes of it ;)

Comment: I have the Arrays.binarySearch returning -10 when searching for the underscore character _ Doing it in debbuger plain sight.

Comment: My special chars array was not sorted, thus the underscore could not be found. Doing an Arrays.sort on it before solved it.

Answer (score 14):

If it's returning a negative value it's not found:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

> public static int binarySearch(Object[] a,
>                                Object key)
>
> **Returns:** index of the search key, if it is contained in the array;
> otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as
> the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index
> of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements
> in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this
> guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key
> is found.

Whatever you're passing in as `uname` is not `"Free"`. I highly suspect you're thinking case doesn't matter (or have trailing characters; whitespace or newline) ;)

Answer (score 9):

Those who are still having this trouble like I was having earlier, and you are thinking that why can't anyone else see that it(Arrays.binarySearch) still have some problems because you have inserted the correct values and you still get the negative results. 
Well this answer is for those:

**It is because your array is not sorted, my friend. Even if it's of characters or strings**

For arrays.binarySearch the array should be sorted(I know, you must be thinking that How did I miss the most important thing (Well yeah, that happens)).

Comment: Incredible but true!

Answer (score 1):

If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array , the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value

Comment: You should post your code and problems not just post the question.